# Facebook og:image is not showing

Tags: php, facebook

`Facebook og:image` is not showing.

I used Facebook debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmuserk.sourcepadstage.com%2Fvideo%2Findex%2F53145ccd4f26109a448b50c6

`og:image` part shows blank but can be clicked.

Here's my meta btw:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/static/img/nega.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Check out what I made on Muserk.com" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Check out what I made on Muserk.com" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Muserk.com gives you the ability to legally add music to your videos and share them with the world!" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
```

My image is `200x200` in size.

And my site has a password, does it affect the `og:image`?

Comment: Yes, man password making its difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your website is password protected. Facebook cant read it content.

So it is showing **Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.**

Comment: Thanks I tried an image from diff. site and it worked. Guess I need to host my image somewhere else.